# Call to a member function getBotUsername() on null in ...vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Request.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, telegram-bot

I'am trying to send a Telegram message with Telegram Bot (`longman/telegram-bot`) and `Laravel Lumen` jobs.

So, first I'am install a Telegram bot with `composer require longman/telegram-bot` and add to composer.json `"Longman\\TelegramBot\\": "vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src"`. Then create a job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Exception\TelegramException;

class ProcessTelegramMessageJob extends Job
{
    const TELEGRAM_API_KEY = 'BOTKEY';
    const TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME = 'BOTNAME';

    protected $telegram;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        try {

            $this->telegram = new Telegram(self::TELEGRAM_API_KEY, self::TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME);
            $this->telegram->handle();

        } catch (TelegramException $e) {}
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $data = [

            'chat_id' => $this->data['user_id'],
            'text' => $this->data['message'],
        ];

        $result = Request::sendMessage($data);
    }
}
```

But, when job try to dispatch, I see in log `Call to a member function getBotUsername() on null in ...vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Request.php`. As I understand Request is not see Telegram instance.

How to fix this error?
Thanks in advance!

PS Dump of telegram object

```
O:28:"Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram":16:{s:10:"*version";s:6:"0.52.0";s:10:"*api_key";s:45:"Api key here";s:15:"*bot_username";s:13:"Bot name here";s:9:"*bot_id";s:9:"470649282";s:8:"*input";s:116:"{"id":1,"url":"cib","_pos":1,"is_vis":true,"deleted_at":null,"checked":false,"data":{"id":1,"_node":1,"head":"CIB"}}";s:17:"*commands_paths";a:1:{i:0;s:98:"/var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/vendor/longman/telegram-bot/src/Commands/SystemCommands";}s:9:"*update";O:35:"Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\Update":9:{s:2:"id";i:1;s:3:"url";s:3:"cib";s:4:"_pos";i:1;s:6:"is_vis";b:1;s:10:"deleted_at";N;s:7:"checked";b:0;s:4:"data";a:3:{s:2:"id";i:1;s:5:"_node";i:1;s:4:"head";s:3:"CIB";}s:8:"raw_data";a:7:{s:2:"id";i:1;s:3:"url";s:3:"cib";s:4:"_pos";i:1;s:6:"is_vis";b:1;s:10:"deleted_at";N;s:7:"checked";b:0;s:4:"data";a:3:{s:2:"id";i:1;s:5:"_node";i:1;s:4:"head";s:3:"CIB";}}s:12:"bot_username";s:13:"Bot name here";}s:14:"*upload_path";N;s:16:"*download_path";N;s:16:"*mysql_enabled";b:0;s:6:"*pdo";N;s:18:"*commands_config";a:0:{}s:14:"*admins_list";a:0:{}s:24:"*last_command_response";O:43:"Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\ServerResponse":4:{s:2:"ok";b:1;s:6:"result";b:1;s:8:"raw_data";a:2:{s:2:"ok";b:1;s:6:"result";b:1;}s:12:"bot_username";N;}s:16:"*botan_enabled";b:0;s:15:"*run_commands";b:0;}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to post this as an issue inside of their github, so they can have a look at it, since it is an interesting issue and it can become bad if it stays like that @Evgeniy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to their [Request documentation](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/blob/master/src/Request.php), your request needs to include $telegram instance first, check the code below

```
$result = Request::initialize($this->telegram)->sendMessage($data);
```

**EDIT:**

Corrected my answer with a working solution, explained why in the comments

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Exception\TelegramException;

class ProcessTelegramMessageJob extends Job
{
    const TELEGRAM_API_KEY = 'BOTKEY';
    const TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME = 'BOTNAME';

    protected $telegram;
    protected $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        try {

            $this->telegram = new Telegram(self::TELEGRAM_API_KEY, self::TELEGRAM_BOT_NAME);
            $this->telegram->handle();
            $data = [
                'chat_id' => $this->data['user_id'],
                'text' => $this->data['message'],
            ];
            $result = Request::sendMessage($data);

        } catch (TelegramException $e) {}
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, now in log another message `Call to a member function sendMessage() on null`.

Comment: Seems to me like you are failing to create Telegram object in your constructor, can you die and dump the exception if its thrown in your constructor?

Comment: Update a question, Telegram object is not null.

Comment: @Evgeniy try `$result = $this->telegram->sendMessage($data);`

Comment: Error again `Call to undefined method Longman\TelegramBot\Telegram::sendMessage()`

Comment: Try moving `$result = Request::sendMessage($data)` along with `$data` object inside of constructor, just below the `$this->telegram->handle();`

Comment: When I place sendMessage in constructor, messages send successful. But why? :) Why they are not send in handle method?

Comment: They tried making a "singleton" out of `Request` but it loses it's context after the block of code is executed, in this case constructor, so when you call `Request::sendMessage` in `handle` function, it's `self:$telegram` instance is null because it's a completely new context. It's just a bad use of "singleton" if we can even call it that

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working code @Evgeniy for other people to know if they encounter the same issue

Comment: Thank you for explanation very much!

Comment: You are welcome, try to post this as an issue on their github too